# Can we explicitly mention the unbundled model version of MLKit barcode to be downloaded by Google Play Services?

Tags: google-play-services, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I am planning to use unbundled barcode model of MLKit. In the documentation
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/installation-paths

it is mentioned that for unbundled models, models will be automatically updated by play services when a new version is released. I want to control the version of the model that google play services is downloading. Can we explicitly ask play services to download the specific version of the model.

To use unbundled version, we need to mention in the manifest like below

<application ...>
...

Can we explicitly mention the version in the value field?